# Gaussian noise is not covering the main image-Python

Tags: python, computer-vision, gaussian

I'm trying to add Gaussian noise to an image("pepper.jpg"). It works, as shown in the result ("noisy pepper.png"); but the noise is not covering the "peppers" and it is around it. Is there something I'm missing in applying noise? 
Any advice would be appreciated.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("pepper.jpg",0)
row, col = img.shape
mean = 0
var = 0.3
sigma = var ** 0.5
gauss = np.random.normal(mean, sigma, (row, col))
gauss = gauss.reshape(row, col)
noisyp = gauss + img
noisyp = noisyp.astype('uint8')
cv2.imwrite('noisy pepper.png', noisyp)
```

[image]

[image]

Regards,
Behrouz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your convertion to *uint8* isn't complex.
Here is what you are looking for:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def convert_to_uint8(image_in):
    temp_image = np.float64(np.copy(image_in))
    cv2.normalize(temp_image, temp_image, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=-1)

    return temp_image.astype(np.uint8)


img = cv2.imread("pepper.jpg", 0)
row, col = img.shape
mean = 0
var = 0.3
sigma = var ** 0.5
gauss = np.random.normal(mean, sigma, (row, col))
gauss = gauss.reshape(row, col)
noisy_pepper = gauss + img

cv2.imwrite('noisy pepper.png', convert_to_uint8(noisy_pepper))
```

[image]

Of course witch such **sigma** you ain't gonna see the noise. Please take look at this one (sigma will be around 14):

```
..
var = 200
sigma = var ** 0.5
..
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Dawid. I appreciate your help.